# Magento 2 Elasticsearch index failing - We can't find products matching the selection

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I have an issue with products disappearing on my Magento stores, it happens randomly and reindexing will sort the issue but restarting the docker image wont. The only error I can see is

`{main} {"exception":"[object] (Elastic\\Elasticsearch\\Exception\\ClientResponseException(code: 404): 404 Not Found: {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"index_not_found_exception\",\"reason\":\"no such index [test_product_1]\",\"resource.type\":\"index_or_alias\",\"resource.id\":\"test_product_1\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"test_product_1\"}],\"type\":\"index_not_found_exception\",\"reason\":\"no such index [test_product_1]\",\"resource.type\":\"index_or_alias\",\"resource.id\":\"test_product_1\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"test_product_1\"},\"status\":404} at /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Response/Elasticsearch.php:65)"} []`

They are running on Plesk with dockers one v7.6.2 and the other 8.4.3, both have different mapping and container names. When it happens I just get "We can't find products matching the selection."